# How to restrict an application to download only in iphone and not in IPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an only iPhone application I don't want to use this application install on iPad because some UI doesn't look good on iPad!

I can select "iPhone" in General-->Deployment Info-->Device

My app install on iPad like mode iPhone 1x size I want to restrict this installation.

Does anyone know to how to restrict app on iPad installation?

Comment: you can select "iPhone" in General-->Deployment Info-->Device but apple will check in iPad and test it. at least app run normally in iPad.

Comment: @NiravKotecha I want to restriction on app store installation on only iPhone app

Comment: i think you can't restrict on app store. in iPad, we have options like "iPhone only" apps which shows your apps.

Comment: Okay Great!, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change Development Devices from Project's general target page.

[image: Xcode Project Sketch from iPad]

from Xcode 11 Beta

[image: Device selection from Xcode 11 Beta]

from Xcode 10.3

[image: Device selection from Xcode 10.3]

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the application by programmatically from app delegate method.
You just check the for current device type.

Than navigate to another screen which is design out of the current storyboard just one screen to tell to user why they are not able to use your application.

NOTE : You have to mention all details in Appstore description to save your application rejection chances.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking that your iOS app will only install in iPhone but not in iPad. Then you can restrict it using the below method that I followed:

In my Xcode 14.3, I need to go to `Build Settings` Tab instead of going to General Tab. After that, just change the `Targeted Device Families`

[image]